# PHP recently viewed script to session array

Tags: php, arrays, session

I've been given this bit of code:

```
if(isset($_GET['viewevent'])) {
    if(count($_SESSION['e_lastviewed']) == 0) {
      $_SESSION['e_lastviewed'][0] = $_GET['viewevent'];
    } else if(!in_array($_GET['viewevent'], $_SESSION['e_lastviewed'])) {
      $_SESSION['e_lastviewed'][2] = $_SESSION['e_lastviewed'][1];
      $_SESSION['e_lastviewed'][1] = $_SESSION['e_lastviewed'][0];
      $_SESSION['e_lastviewed'][0] = $_GET['viewevent'];
    }
  }
  if($_GET['show']) {
    $_SESSION['show'] = $_GET['show'];
  } else if($_SESSION['show']=='') {
    $_SESSION['show'] = "all";
  }
```

It apparently saves ID's of recently viewed items, so i need to put these id's into an array. 
Would this work?

```
$my_array = array($_SESSION['e_lastviewed'][2],$_SESSION['e_lastviewed'][1],$_SESSION['e_lastviewed'][0]);
```

I've ran it but it displays blank results (not sure if thats due to me not doing it right or incomplete code...Have i missed something? I'm not sure if i completley understand the script i was given...

Comment: This should be right... Had you tried to output the array?

Comment: Try printing `$_SESSION` with `<pre><?php print_r($_SESSION);?></pre>` and post results

Comment: have you started session?

Comment: Need to be more elaorative

Comment: Sorry! 
Yes the session has been started, i've tried many options of outputting and it all seems blank..This is the output from print_r($_SESSION)
[code]Array ( [show] => all [user_id] => 1 [account_type_id] => 2 [user_name] => IanManager [group_name] => Manager [real_name] => Ian Cozens [API_acctype] => 2 [API_accfrom] => clients [API_userid] => 1 )  [/code]

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
  if ( !isset($_SESSION['e_lastviewed']) )
    $_SESSION['e_lastviewed'] = array();

  // alt: while(count($_SESSION['e_lastviewed']) > 2 ) {
  if(count($_SESSION['e_lastviewed']) > 2 ) {
    array_shift($_SESSION['e_lastviewed']); // drop off from 3

  array_unshift($_SESSION['e_lastviewed'],$_GET['viewevent']); // insert in the beginning

  if($_GET['show']) {
    $_SESSION['show'] = $_GET['show'];
  } else if($_SESSION['show']=='') {
    $_SESSION['show'] = "all";
  }
```

Comment: thanks for the help - it says theres a syntax error with `code`$_SESSION['e_lastviewed'] = array();`code`